# how to reduce redux boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to redux and I find that every little thing x turns into x_success and x_failure, usually when fetching data or trying to create a new entity, and that means more action creators, and more handling in the reducers. What's the recommended approach here? thanks.

Comment: If you are only working with data in CRUD format, you can use [redux-data-entity](https://github.com/iamawebgeek/redux-data-entity), this library would allow you get rid of most of the boilerplate, there is also offline support [redux-data-entity-offline](https://github.com/iamawebgeek/redux-data-entity-offline)

Comment: you might want to check out Redux Starter Kit from the react team: https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/

Answer (score 2):

Recommended approach is x_success, x_failure etc. But this is for async operations only. Let's see why :

Async operations in your SPA are the operations you want to know

1. when operation started,
2. when you got response back
3. Type of response , success or failure

So that you will have seperate actions creator functions which return objects and one async action creator function which can return function instead of object and  calls other action creators from its body.

For the reasons above you should have seperate action creators, one async action creator and of course for every action creator you should have a constant in your reducer.

Assuming you are writing your constants, actions and reducers in seperate folders, this can be a nightmare. If this is the case, you should take a look at here [duck modular redux](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) .

Duck modular redux is something you should definetely implement to reduce the boilerplate. Other things like seperate action creators, seperate constants, seperately checking on reducers for constants are required. There is nothing to feel bad about it.

Answer (score 0):

I started to work with Redux almost since the beginning of its story, 2 years ago. While it is a great thing and it allows to eliminate a whole type of bugs and makes all business logic more explicit, it has a lot of concepts. For each entity, you need to create:

- constants (for each state -- in case of async function, there are three of them, for start, failure and success)
- action (function)
- reducer (update state, sometimes a nested update)

It was mentioned that you can something like redux-ducks, which is an approach to organize your code, but you will not write less of the code. So, I strongly believe people should consider writing their own wrapper around redux more seriously.

I wrote a library [redux-tiles](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles), which deals exactly with this kind of situations -- it takes the burden of creating constants, update the state (so you don't need to write a reducer by yourself), and do nested updates if needed. So, code for async request, will look something like this:

```
import { createTile } from 'redux-tiles';
const apiRequest = createTile({
  type: ['api', 'request'],
  fn: ({ api, params }) => api.get('/api/items', params),
});
```

It also allows you to combine other actions easier, because in the `fn` you have access to `dispatch` and `actions`. You can take a look at more examples [here](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

I started using Redux and I loved the concept, but I got really annoyed by the big amount of boilerplate. I ended up creating **[actionware](https://github.com/wellguimaraes/actionware)** lib. Basically here's what you have with actionware:

- no more action creators and action types, just actions (simple functions) and reducers
- actions dispatch their result automatically
- error status for every
- action with no extra code busy status for every async action (yep, no extra code!)
- cancellable actions

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can reduce the bolierplate. Here's an excellent resource from official repo:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.md

Besides, there are various community-driven libraries that help you in reducing redux boilerplate and in organising your store better. Redux Box might interest you in this regard:

https://github.com/anish000kumar/redux-box

Answer (score 0):

A *huge* Boilerplate is one of the drawbacks of the flux architecture in general. You might want to checkout [redux-fluent](https://github.com/Code-Y/redux-fluent), it has been designed with that in mind.

```js
import { createAction, createReducer, ofType } from 'redux-fluent';

const addTodo = createAction('todos | add');

export const todos = createReducer('todos')
  .actions(
    ofType(actions.addTodo).map(
      (state, { payload }) => state.concat(payload),
    ),
  )
  .default(() => []);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce Redux boilerplate you can generate action creators and reducer **by describing one function** with `redux-blaze`:

```
import { buildReducer } from "redux-blaze";

export const { actionCreators, reducer: filtersReducer } = buildReducer(initialState, {
    setMySearch: ({ search }) /* <- payload */ => state => ({ ...state, search }),
    setCategory: ({ category }) => state => ({ ...state, category }),
    setSort: ({ sort }) => state => ({ ...state, sort }),
}, {
    prefix: 'MY_FILTER',
});

...

// Just add auto generated reducer to root reducer:
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  filters: filtersReducer
})

...

// dispatch an action:
dispatch(actionCreators.setCategory({category: 'my category'}))
```

You can also find TypeScript examples here:
https://github.com/spiderpoul/redux-blaze